# Error_WINHTTP timeout

Tags: azure-devops

When running the powershell script for the VSTS agent installation in target server, the script runs, it creates an agent directory A1 and copies files inside it but then after some point of time, the scripts asks for the ServerURL and PAT to which I enter the details of my organization's VSTS URL and the PAT generated in the script but then it fails to move ahead.

And In the error log, it displays

(WinHttp Error: ERROR_WINHTTP_TIMEOUT).

It tries to connect 4 times but do not connect and then timeout after 4 attempts.

Comment: What are you entering for the server URI? Are you sure appropriate firewall rules are in place to allow HTTPS traffic?

Comment: I am entering g******.visualstudio.com as my server URL which is also there as a parameter in the powershell script but it is not able to take it up..don't know why! Yes, firewall rules are in place because I am able to access the server URI through chrome browser.